# Подогнать сайт по медиа-запросу

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивность

Ребята подскажите, пожалуйста, подганяю сайт по  медиозапросу,

```
/* 576-768px */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

и выпирают какие -то падинги,синего цвета

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите разобраться

Comment: покажите код, для этого есть в меню "фрагмент кода"

Comment: покажите конкретно материал и я вам помогу. я не могу оставлять комментарии.